# Envoy with AWS E2C instance. "No healthy upstream" error

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, yaml, grpc, envoyproxy

I have a simple Greeter client-server repository:
https://github.com/limeniye/GreeterGrpcWebGateway

And it works for both cases on my local machine:

```
var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://localhost:5001"); // gRPC service
```

```
var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://localhost:8080"); // envoy proxy
```

But when I'am trying to use it from AWS E2C instance it works only for the first case (gRPC).
When I'am using something like folowing example:

```
var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://52.58.230.171:8080"); // envoy proxy
```

I have an error: No healthy upstream.

**envoy.yaml**

```yaml
admin:
  access_log_path: /tmp/admin_access.log
  address:
    socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 9902 }

static_resources:
  listeners:
  - name: listener_0
    address:
      socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 8080 }
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.network.http_connection_manager.v2.HttpConnectionManager
          codec_type: auto
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: local_service
              domains: ["*"]
              routes:
              - match: { prefix: "/" }
                route:
                  cluster: echo_service
                  max_grpc_timeout: 0s
              cors:
                allow_origin_string_match:
                - prefix: "*"
                allow_methods: GET, PUT, DELETE, POST, OPTIONS
                allow_headers: keep-alive,user-agent,cache-control,content-type,content-transfer-encoding,custom-header-1,x-accept-content-transfer-encoding,x-accept-response-streaming,x-user-agent,x-grpc-web,grpc-timeout
                max_age: "1728000"
                expose_headers: custom-header-1,grpc-status,grpc-message
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.http.grpc_web
          - name: envoy.filters.http.cors
          - name: envoy.filters.http.router
  clusters:
  - name: echo_service
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    type: logical_dns
    http2_protocol_options: {}
    lb_policy: round_robin
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: cluster_0
      endpoints:
        - lb_endpoints:
            - endpoint:
                address:
                  socket_address:
                    address: host.docker.internal
                    port_value: 5001
```

I already tried to use `docker network create`, but it didn't help me.

```
$ docker network create test-net
$ docker container run --network test-net --rm -d -it --name envoy -p 8080:8080 -p 9902:9902 limeniye/greeter-envoy
$ docker run --network test-net --name greeter-service limeniye/greeter-service
```

Comment: Here is `port_value: 5001` in your yaml, but you are trying to connect via `5051`. Is it typo?...

Comment: @rzlvmp, oh this is mistake in post. I updated post, thank you.

Comment: @rzlvmp, also I added the repository to post.
I'll be appreciative if you will check it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with gRPC so can't do exact answer. But if I understand this correctly, envoy is trying to access gRPC service container on port 5001 when you are accessing 8080. So you may try to set `greeter-service` instead of `host.docker.internal`. `host.docker.internal` is using to be able connect from container to docker host. And your case is a connection between two containers. You don't need to use docker host

Comment: @rzlvmp, thank you for your answer!
A couple hours ago I changed `host.docker.internal` to public AWS instance ip, like `address: 3.122.94.127` . It helps me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer: `address: host.docker.internal` -> `address: 3.122.94.127`